# mysql TRIGGER update field after update

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have 2 table today_plan and kiln_master.

after  pattern  and itemno inserted  to today_plan then need to select matching **yeild from kiln_master** table and update this value  to  **yeild field in today_plan**.

i have created a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_yeild AFTER INSERT ON today_plan
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE today_plan
  SET yeild= (SELECT kiln_master.yeild from kiln_master,today_plan WHERE today_plan.itemno = kiln_master.item  AND  today_plan.pattern = kiln_master.pattern ) WHERE  itemno=new.itemno AND pattern=new.pattern
```

what part is wrong with my code

**today_plan**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS decsys.today_plan;
CREATE TABLE `today_plan` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `belt` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `distant` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `pjtno` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pattern` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `itemno` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `pro_qty` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `act_qty` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `yeild` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `remark` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `shipment` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `temp` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `fire_date` date NOT NULL,
  `kiln` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kiln_plan` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `kiln_act` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `ins_date` date NOT NULL,
  `ins_act` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `plandate` date NOT NULL,
  `ship_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**kiln_master**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS decsys.kiln_master;
CREATE TABLE `kiln_master` (
  `kid` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `pattern` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `yeild` double NOT NULL,
  `temp` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `kiln` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**error**

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'today_plan' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to update the row after it has been inserted, isn't it better to do before so that it gets inserted with the correct values? That'd be something like;

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_yeild BEFORE INSERT ON today_plan
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.yeild = COALESCE((SELECT kiln_master.yeild 
                   FROM kiln_master
                   WHERE NEW.itemno = kiln_master.item  
                   AND  NEW.pattern = kiln_master.pattern
                   LIMIT 1), 0);
```